# USB tethering from Android 2.3

Tags: 12.04, usb, android, usb-modem, tethering

I used a friend's Android (2.3) phone that allows USB tethering, subheading: "share phone's mobile network with PC."

Android lets me set 2 tethering settings, under "USB tethering type":

> - Windows
> - Mac OS X

Naturally, Linux isn't officially supported, but I suspect someone has run into this before.  What do I need to on my Ubuntu 12.04 setup to get it to recognize either of these connection types for USB tethering?

Comment: Can't you try both and test which works better?

Comment: You would be better off if your friend would root their phone... then it would work across the board without giving an OS option.

Comment: I do USB tethering all the time with my Android phone, but per the above it is rooted and using a custom ROM.. CM 7.2. Once the phone is in tether mode, Ubuntu recognizes it as a "wired" connection, no other configuration is required.

Comment: @desgua, I tried both and neither worked!  I suspect rooting may be the only solution, unless there's something on the ubuntu-end that can mimic PC or MacOS and solve this.

Comment: Maybe you can get an app at Google Play to just turn on usb tethering, default? It works great at Ubuntu.

Comment: please name the phone?

Comment: HTC doubleshot / MyTouch 4G Slide

Comment: I tried samsung galaxy Y with Airtel 3G network,amazingly Ubuntu 12.04 gives me option of plug and play

Comment: on 14.04, with a galaxy nexus, it works seamlessly and immediately - too easy!

Comment: I had a problem connecting to usb tether.  Try autoethernet in the network icon menu (top ubuntu menu bar).  It worked after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My last phone ran Android 2.3 and i had no problems with USB tethering. I could set the USB connection to default to tethering and all i had to do was plug it in to my Linux laptop and it was online. So it's not Android 2.3 - but it may be your carrier. I believe Optus may not allow tethering on prepaid. I'm with Telstra and they do.

Comment: I think you're right---oddly, it was setting the default that worked, rather than just changing the current setting.  I assume without changing the default, it was still trying to mount the drive or something?  Not sure, but it works fine now.

Comment: gsm galaxy nexus here.  I only have the option to enable usb teethering, no prompt about OS type.

Comment: @FredThomsen: That prompt only appears if no OS is set in the tethering options.

Answer (score 1):

Yes..I have also experienced same problem.
This is due to carrier.
I am from India. 
There are two carriers namely IDEA and AirTel.
I was able to connect with IDEA on 3G but for AIRTEL no luck
but when I switched Airtel network to 2G, I was able to connect sadly speed was low.
May be you can change the network type