# how to use android usb internet tethering for old Ubuntu PC

Tags: usb, internet, android

I have one old desktop PC which don't have internet, so I want to use my Android phone to connect this pc to the ADSL modem from WiFi connection.

If possible I want to find out how could I use **android usb internet tethering** to give the pc internet Access.

Thank.

Comment: Any currently supported Ubuntu release supports USB tethering, no user action required, other than connecting the USB cable and enabling that function in the phone. What exactly are you having trouble with? Ubuntu release/version?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/144301/usb-tethering-from-android-2-3#167071

Comment: Ok I didn't know it work. I will test it.